# Xamarin Android UI issues in low end devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin Android application issues.**

In lower android os devices my application have some UI issues(hang/flickering) while navigating from one page to another also navigating back. But in higher android os device it is working smoothly. My pages has only labels,buttons and images (maximum 5-6 Xamarin default controls). Also in iOS application there is no such UI hang issues.
What would be the reason for such device specific issues? How can I resolve such issues.

Comment: What type of images do you have? Are they small icons? or larger images? Any background images? The issue is most likely the hardware. Unlike Apple, who controls the hardware and iOS, Google doesn't control the hardware of low end devices. There isn't a whole lot you can do about the performance on low-end android devices.

Comment: Could be hardware or image size but it could also be code blocking the UI thread that affects all devices but is just more apparent on the low end devices.